# tz.localize() returning incorrect offset

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, pytz

I have the following function (with exaggerated logger statements just to help with debugging right now) that takes an input timezone and datetime, and converts it to PST:

```
def convert_to_pst_equivalent_time(input_datetime, input_timezone):
    timezone = pytz.timezone(input_timezone)
    dt_date = input_datetime.split("T")[0]
    dt_time = input_datetime.split("T")[1].split("-")[0] if "-" in input_datetime.split("T")[1] else \
        input_datetime.split("T")[1].split("+")[0]
    dt = datetime.strptime((dt_date + " " + dt_time), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    logger.info("DT is: {}".format(dt))

    dt = timezone.localize(dt)
    logger.info("DT is now: {}".format(dt))

    dt = dt.astimezone(pytz.timezone("America/Los_Angeles"))
    logger.info("DT is finally: {}".format(dt))

    return dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
```

If we have some inputs like "2020-02-03T00:00:00" as "input_datetime" and "Pacific/Norwalk" as the input_timezone, my outputs are the following:

```
DT is: 2020-02-03 00:00:00
DT is now: 2020-02-03 00:00:00+12:00
DT is finally: 2020-02-02 04:00:00-08:00
```

However, based on this website (https://www.zeitverschiebung.net/en/difference/timezone/pacific--norfolk/city/5368361), Pacific/Norwalk should be +11:00, not +12:00, and therefore, my final output after converting to Los Angeles time is also off by 1 hour. Strangely, this is working for other timezones, but this one in particular is offering problems. I've tried doing things like replacing tzinfo= and localize() (*as seen above*) but neither appear to be returning the right offset. Any ideas?

Comment: "Norwalk, California is located in the Pacific Time Zone, which means that the time is Pacific Standard Time (PST) UTC-08:00 during regular time and Pacific Daylight Time (PDT) UTC-07:00 when daylight savings is in effect."

Comment: I see.. but it isn't currently Daylight Savings though? Is there a way to approach this with a flag or something that can detect if it is currently Daylight Savings? And if there is a way to do this for countries that follow Daylight Savings? I know there are a handful that don't, so I want to avoid hardcoding it in a way that assumes all timezones abide by that.

Comment: are you in Norwalk? `.localize` is converting to your local computer's timezone.

Comment: I'm not, but I am close to it (Los Angeles). Do I need to update my OS or something?

Comment: look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7338508/why-is-pytz-offset-incorrect